# is there a algorithmic problem that can cause code in python don't give us specific outpu?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that takes n number of input in any kind of integer or float. I wanted to make  this program a calculator with n number of input in any kind (int/float)
but I think for some algorithmic reason in writing code,
I can't give integer to the program after it find out it's int.

```
print("start")
b=int(input("The number of numbers in operations: "))
for a in range (b):
  c=input("choose format of numbers integer or float?")
if c=="integer":
  int(input("integer number:"))
elif c=="float":
  float(input("float number :"))
```

Comment: Please rephrase your post to make it more clear what the current action is and what the intended action is. You also do not assign the value of the input statements to anything.

Comment: you convert your input to int/float and discard the converted value immediately because you do not store it inside a variable ... some more python tutorials needed maybe?

Comment: For the purposes of a calculator, the difference between an int of `1` and float `1.0` shouldn't matter, so why not always use floats? Other than that, your loop is running to completion before `c ==` conditions are checked

Comment: yes have point i think you are right i can just use float.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with indentation your code should be indented like this:

```
print("start")
b=int(input("The number of numbers in operations: "))
for a in range (b):
  c=input("choose format of numbers integer or float?")
  if c=="integer":
     int(input("integer number:"))
  elif c=="float":
     float(input("float number :"))
```

the if - elif statement should be at the same indentation level as the for loop

Comment: thanks but that does not work too

Comment: You should provide your desired output in the question in order for other people to help you figure it out.